# How to add the deleted item's quantity back in my total quantities in django?

Tags: python, django

I am designing a model of the Health Center. If I am deleting the prescribed medicines to a patient, then I want those medicines' quantity back in the total stock of that medicine.

e.g. Suppose I have total of 50 of **medicine A** in my stocks. If I prescribed 2 unit(quantity) of medicine A to a patient, then total remained in the stock will be 48, and suppose now I am deleting that entry, then I want total 50 stocks of **medicine A** back again.

How do I solve this problem. I am a beginner in Django.

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far? The code for your model for instance would help as well as the code for this deleting operation.

Comment: Thanks, for taking a look. Now I have solved the problem using Django's signals method pre_delete. Thanks again @Glenn DJ.